# How to the data to be loaded from file/api for first render and from the state for subsequent render in react, redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am very new to react and redux. I was loading a local json file, a list of contacts, in componentWillMount(). I am copying the data from file to state as well(in reducers).

But I am performing some action like add, delete and update contacts with the data loaded in the state.

My problem is after first render I want the data to loaded from the state and not from the local file. I know that componentWillMount will load data from file and not from state for every rendering.

I tried playing with different react lifecycles but failed?
Is there way?

In short I want the data to be loaded from file for first render and from the state for subsequent render

```
export class ContactsIndex extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchInitialContacts();
  }
  render() {........}
 }



export function fetchInitialContacts() {
 const request = axios.get(ROOT_URL);
  return (dispatch) => {
    request.then(({data}) => {
        dispatch({  type: 'GET_INITIAL_CONTACTS', contactsListPayload:data })
    });
}
}
```

Comment: You mean, even if you refresh the page?, or only in normal navigation?. If it's normal navigation you can do it with **redux** and placing a condition in your compoentWillMount, otherwise you will need to persist the state somewhere.

Comment: I am using react-routes. Rigth now my  state is like this                                                   const INITIAL_STATE = { contactsArray : [], singleContact: null };              Do you mean I need to create a flag or a extra parameter in the state       e.g   const INITIAL_STATE = { contactsArray : [], singleContact: null, intitailLoad: false };

Comment: You can use **contactsArray.length** if 0 dispatch `GET_INITIAL_CONTACTS` else just use **contactsArray**, it will hold the values. But if you refresh the page the state will be lost.

Comment: That solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In a react-redux application lifecycle, you are connecting your component class using a function usually named `mapStateToProps`. This function is responsible for passing down properties to your react component. You then don't need to handle your responses within your component's state anymore.

For achieving this you have to extend your code to something like this:

```
export class ContactsIndex extends Component {
  render() {
    // access your contacts like this
    return <div>
      { this.props.contacts }
      </div>;
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    contacts: state.contacts
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ContactsIndex)
```

Somewhere in your app intialization or in componentWillReceiveProps you can then dispatch your GET_INITIAL_CONTACTS action:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  // if contacts are unset, call the action and load them:
  if (nextProps.contacts === null) {
     this.props.dispatch(fetchInitialContactsAction());
  }
}
```

Within your reducer you are mapping the contacts to the global state index "contacts", which is then automatically available as this.props.contacts from within your component, because it is passed down to it by mapStateToProps.

This is an example of your reducer:

```
initialState = { contacts: null }; // initialstate for contacts has to be null in order to work
function contacts(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_INITIAL_CONTACTS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        contacts: action.data // data should hold your contacts
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

You can read more about it in the redux docs: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options

Read about reducers here http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html

Comment: This is what I did, but I don't know where to initialize the initial fetching request. i,e fetchInitialContacts(). If I do it in componentWillMount(). Everytime component will invoke this function and load the data from the file and not from the state. I want to invoke this action only once and for other subsequent renders, I have written a different action.

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how to only fetch it once, see the componentWillReceiveProps part